# What are the differences between the etymology of "ingenious" and "ingenuous"?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, greek

As a matter of fact, I don't know whether there is any difference between the source words in bold below:

From Latin **ingeniosus** (“endowed with good natural capacity, gifted with genius”), from ingenium (“innate or natural quality, natural capacity, genius”), from in (“in”) + gignere (“to produce”), Old Latin genere. Compare French ingénieux; see also engine.

From Latin **ingenuus** ("of noble character, frank")

And I wanna know the help of discerning the Modern meanings of those two words with the grammatical suffixes in Old Latin or Greek above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The account by *Daily Writing Tips* that Roaring Fish presents is correct for the recent history. But it stops about 2000 years ago, when it actually goes back at least 4000.

The root in each of these words comes from the Proto-Indo-European root ****genə***- (or ****gen***-), meaning 'birth' and all the concepts attendant on it -- including noble birth, which gives rise to both the English words *kind* and *gentle*, which were once used to talk about the way those of noble birth behaved.

Some of the other descendants (***Cognates***, literally 'born together') of PIE **genə-* are shown in [this chart](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf), which distinguishes literal descent from borrowings; after a few generations nobody notices whether a word is "native" or not, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Google has the answer.

[Ingenious vs. Ingenuous](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/ingenious-vs-ingenuous-2/)

Comment: A link is not an answer. Please summarize what the link says, and why you think it is an accurate answer.

Comment: Given that the op

Comment: Um, something ate most of that comment...

Comment: Indeed... but I am not sure by what.

Comment: Try again: given that the OP practically answers his own question, plus his previous question, plus the numerous times the same question appears in other forums, I don't see it as a serious question deserving of a detailed answer. Particularly when the answer is so easily found by asking Google....

Comment: @Roaring Fish: I completely agree with the above comment, but I still think it would have been better to post the link in the answer as a comment to the question.

Comment: Pooh. Why not have the answers be in complementary distribution, as they currently are? This is good etymology and Roaring Fish saved me having to do it. Why should this answer get downvoted? Silly politics...